# Create and new view from existing view

Tags: java, android, android-view

I've been working on an app that displays feeds in a list activity.
At first, I'm getting the information and parsing it, and I put it in a array of "FeedType" that I've created, that has 3 fields: Bitmap pic, String name and View content.
The content represent the feed's content, and there's different type of contents.
This array is being initialized in the parsing process.

I created the feed layout in a xml file.
Created a ImageView, TextView and LinearLayout that will contain the "content" by using addView().
I've created a wrapper and create my ListAdapter to reuse the object in the list.

My problem start when I'm trying to use add a view who is already a child of other LinearLayout, and it's happening because when I retrieve the content from the array I'm retireving the reference to the existing view, and not a new view.

Is there a way to create a new view from existing view? Or somebody got other solution?

Code:

```
public class FeedType {

    private Bitmap profilePicSrc;
    private String name;
    private View feedContent;
    private Context context;
    private final String PIC_BASE_SRC = "xxx";
    private final String PIC_END_SRC = "xxx";


    public FeedType(String contactId, String name, View feedContent, Context context){
        try {
            this.profilePicSrc = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(PIC_BASE_SRC + contactId.toString() + PIC_END_SRC).getContent());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.name = name;
        this.context = context;
        this.feedContent = feedContent;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public Bitmap getProfilePicture(){
        return profilePicSrc;
    }

    public View getContent(){
        return this.feedContent;
    }
}
```

Wrapper class:

```
public class FeedWrapper {

    private View base;
    private ImageView pic = null;
    private TextView name = null;
    private LinearLayout content = null;

    public FeedWrapper(View base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    public ImageView getProfilePicture() {
        if (pic == null) {
            pic = (ImageView)base.findViewById(R.id.pic);
        }
        return(pic);
    }

    public TextView getName() {
        if (name == null) {
            name = (TextView)base.findViewById(R.id.name);
        }
        return(name);
    }

    public LinearLayout getContent() {
        if (content == null) {
            content = (LinearLayout)base.findViewById(R.id.content);
        }
        else content.removeAllViews();
        return(content);
    }

}
```

ListAdapter class:

```
private class FeedListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {

        public FeedListAdapter() {
            super(Feeds.this, R.layout.feed, new Object[feedArrLength]);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View feed = convertView;
            FeedWrapper wrapper = null;

            if (feed == null) {

                feed = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.feed, parent, false);
                wrapper = new FeedWrapper(feed);
                feed.setTag(wrapper);
            }
            else {
                wrapper = (FeedWrapper)feed.getTag();
            }

            wrapper.getName().setText(arr.get(position).getName());
            wrapper.getProfilePicture().setImageBitmap(arr.get(position).getProfilePicture());
            wrapper.getContent().addView(arr.get(position).getContent());
            return(feed);
        }
    }
```

I know that's a bit difficult to understand, if you have questions please ask.

Thanks in advance, Elad!

Comment: You say "My problem start when I'm trying to use add a view who is already a child of other LinearLayout". What exactly proble do you have? Any exception? Can you show exception log?

Comment: Yes, I have an exception:
E/AndroidRuntime(  376): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a wrong way to keep View in **FeedType** object. Keep only data in FeedType.

For example create new class **FeedContent** which contains parsed data about feed content (not any views):

```
class FeedContent {

... // i.e. private List<String> contents;

}
```

Then change your **FeedType** class:

```
public class FeedType {

private Bitmap profilePicSrc;
private String name;
private FeedContent feedContent;
private Context context;
private final String PIC_BASE_SRC = "xxx";
private final String PIC_END_SRC = "xxx";


public FeedType(String contactId, String name, FeedContent feedContent, Context context){
    try {
        this.profilePicSrc = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(PIC_BASE_SRC + contactId.toString() + PIC_END_SRC).getContent());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    this.name = name;
    this.context = context;
    this.feedContent = feedContent;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public Bitmap getProfilePicture(){
    return profilePicSrc;
}

public FeedContent getContent(){
    return this.feedContent;
}
```

}

And then make your **FeedListAdapter** like:

```
private class FeedListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {

    public FeedListAdapter() {
        super(Feeds.this, R.layout.feed, new Object[feedArrLength]);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View feed = convertView;
        FeedWrapper wrapper = null;

        if (feed == null) {

            feed = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.feed, parent, false);
            wrapper = new FeedWrapper(feed);
            feed.setTag(wrapper);
        }
        else {
            wrapper = (FeedWrapper)feed.getTag();
        }

        wrapper.getName().setText(arr.get(position).getName());
        wrapper.getProfilePicture().setImageBitmap(arr.get(position).getProfilePicture());
        View feedContentView = createContentView(arr.get(position).getContent());
        wrapper.getContent().addView(feedContentView);
        return(feed);
    }

    private View createContentView(FeedContent feedContent) {
        ... // Here you shuold inflate new view and fill it with data from "feedContent"
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about but wanted to use it if no other option available, because creating the feed type list is a thread and this happen on the fly so it might slow down the list. Thanks I will try it!